# casperjs getelementbyid working but getelementbyname not working

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

okay i am trying to fill input fields on a html page that have no form i am trying this work around for specific reasons and only require to do it the way i am trying.

basically here is my html

```
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" nowrap width="120">Amount: <font size="2" color="#CC0000">*</font>    </td>
    <td width="490">
    <input type="text" name="data" size="20" maxlength="20" value="">
    <select name="Percent"><option value="2" >NUM</option><option value="1" >num2</option><option value="3" selected>resultin</option></select>
    <div class="error"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
   <td width="490">
      <input type="text" name="account" id="account" size="20" maxlength="20" value="">
    </td>
```

now when i use this to insert text into the account field every thing works

```
if(casper.exists(ac1)){
var uel = "https://example.com";
this.thenOpen(uel, function() {
casper.wait(10000, function() {    
  casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
      document.getElementById('account').value = '345de';


    });
casper.wait(10000, function() {
  casper.then(function() {
    this.capture("filenadfgmedsfg.jpg");
    var el2 = this.getHTML();
    fs.write('results23.html', el2, 'w');
});
});
});
```

but when i try either of these below to fill the input data field i cannot get it to work

```
if(casper.exists(ac1)){
var uel = "https://example.com";
this.thenOpen(uel, function() {
casper.wait(10000, function() {    
  casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
      document.getElementById('data').value = '345de';


    });
casper.wait(10000, function() {
  casper.then(function() {
    this.capture("filenadfgmedsfg.jpg");
    var el2 = this.getHTML();
    fs.write('results23.html', el2, 'w');
});
});
});
```

and this one does not work please help me fix this

```
if(casper.exists(ac1)){
var uel = "https://example.com";
this.thenOpen(uel, function() {
casper.wait(10000, function() {    
  casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
      document.getElementByName('data').value = '345de';


    });
casper.wait(10000, function() {
  casper.then(function() {
    this.capture("filenadfgmedsfg.jpg");
    var el2 = this.getHTML();
    fs.write('results23.html', el2, 'w');
});
});
});
```

can anyone show me a way of filling the data field using a simaler way to getElementBy technique

Comment: Open your browser's developer console to check for errors. This should be the first place you look when encountering problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `getElementByName()`.  What you probably want is `getElementsByName()` and it returns a list of elements, not just a single element so you have to either just get the first item in the list or process the whole list (depending upon what you want to do).

```
var uel = "https://example.com";
this.thenOpen(uel, function () {
    casper.wait(10000, function () {
        casper.then(function () {
            this.evaluate(function () {
                document.getElementsByName('data')[0].value = '345de';
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName('data').value ='0.01'; i tried this but still does not fill it

Comment: @user3407899 - Please read what's in my answer.  `getElementsByName()` returns a list of objects, not a single object.  You should also learn how to look for error messages in your the browser error console or debug console because that will often also tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i have the casper console open i get no errors i will try my browser console in a moment

Comment: @user3407899 - You would have gotten error messages on the two things you tried in your original code that didn't work.  Here what you tried was just adding a `.value` property to the returned list object so it wasn't an error, but didn't do what you want either.  Did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: thanks jfriend yes i seen them error can you helpe me with one other thing if you can how can i click this html button <input value="Payment preview" name="submit" class="button" id="sbt" type="submit">

Comment: @user3407899 - you can get the form object and call `.submit()` on it.  You can also get the button object call call `.click()` on it.